# Need assistance for a part with json/php

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I need help for generate the series data part into json

```javascript
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 71.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 106.4],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 129.2],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 144.0],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 176.0]
         ]
    }]
});
```

**My php part**

```php
foreach ($behaviour as $value) {
    $chart['xAxis']['categories'][]= time($value['date']);
}
```

**Json output**

```
[1318354710,1318354710,1318354710,1318354710]
```

I don't know what I need to do with my `php` code to do this part with a valid json.

**part where I need help**

```php
series: [{
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 71.5],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 106.4],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 129.2],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 144.0],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 176.0]
     ]
}]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9]` is **not** valid JSON; it is JavaScript. Also, the first code is apparently already JavaScript - why do you want to convert it to JavaScript? Also, note that php's `time` function doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Cause I have more than 100000 chart to generate , I need to generate all my chart with  a database  , and I use json to create my chart

Comment: @phihag:  I believe "the first code" is the output that the OP wants to generate using PHP.

Comment: What format and timezone is `$value['date']` stored in?

Comment: And I believe  I need to day an array with my php for doing a valid output json ( for the series[( data .... part) ?

Comment: If I understand you right, then yes, the brackets `[` and `]` indicate an array in JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.UTC` returns the number of milliseconds in a date string since midnight of January 1, 1970. This is the same as a UNIX timestamp. So `[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9]` translates to `[1262304000, 29.9]`.

There are a number of ways to get this timestamp in PHP. One simple (and object oriented) way is to use the DateTime class:

```php
$time = new DateTime($value['date'], new DateTimezone('UTC'));
$chart['xAxis']['categories'][] = $time->getTimestamp();
```

### Update

Without knowing the ins and outs of your code, the best I can do is offer some sample code:

```
<?php
// sample data
$behaviour = array(
    array(
        'date' => '2010-01-01',
        'datum' => 29.9
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2010-01-02',
        'datum' => 71.5
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2010-01-03',
        'datum' => 106.4
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2010-01-06',
        'datum' => 129.2
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2010-01-07',
        'datum' => 144
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2010-01-08',
        'datum' => 176
    )
);

// creates the container information
$output = array(
    'chart' => array(
        'renderTo' => 'container'
    ),

    'xAxis' => array(
        'type' => 'datetime'
    ),

    'series' => array()
);

// adds the sample data
foreach ($behaviour as $value) {
    $time = new DateTime($value['date'], new DateTimezone('UTC'));
    $output['series'][0]['data'][] = array(
        $time->getTimestamp(), $value['datum']
    );
}

// output as JSON
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output); 
?>
```

Feel free to adapt it to your actual code.

Comment: Ahh thx for this part ! :)  And do you know how I need to do my php code  for  generate   my   series: [{data: [  part ? All the DATA in the jquery are in a array (   [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],   [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 71.5],) , but in my json outpout  for DATA part look like that [1318354710,1318354710,1318354710,1318354710]

Comment: I added some sample code to illustrate how to create the JSON data. The output can be assigned to `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart()` using an AJAX callback routine for instance, or constructed using the string returned from `json_encode`.